# error makefile C- opengl

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, opengl, makefile

I am trying to compile a .c file containing c-code for opengl.
But I keep getting the following error:
Interesting question. 
    undefined reference to 'glClear'
    undefined reference to 'gluLookAt'
    undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
    undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
    undefined reference to 'glLineWidth'
    undefined reference to 'glBegin'
    undefined reference to 'glVertex3d'
    undefined reference to 'glEnd'
    etc...

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my source code as it is example code that has been provided to us.

the headers i included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

How could I fix this issue?

FYI: I am compiling this on ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
my3DTest: clean $(OBJS)
    LDOPTS=\
    cc -o my3DTest $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS)
```

the variable LDOPTS assignment is continued into the next line, due to the backslash (`\`), thereby your `cc` command is just assigned to that variable. Once that's done *make* continues by using its standard implicit target rules to build the binary. But since you didn't specify the linker options in a variable that *make* will use for that implicit rule, it will try to link without these variables.

---

Makefile, assuming that the sourcefile is names `vlucht.c`.

**Important Notice:** *Indentation and whitespace does matter in a Makefile. Improper indentation will corrupt the Makefile!*

```
LDLIBS = -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXt -lXext -lm
EXE  = vlucht
OBJS = vlucht.o

.PHONY: clean

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)

clean:
    -$(RM) -f $(EXE) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: so what do you suggest? Should I just remove the backslash? Because strangely that worked previously fine for previous pieces of code..

Comment: @privetDruzia: First things first I suggest you learn how Makefiles work and the makefile syntax. And I recommend removing the line `LDOPTS=\` because it makes zero sense.

Comment: ok thanks for your critics... I removed LDOPTS, didn't solve anything. So I have a problem and your answer to my problem "just go and learn" and you didn't solve my issue, very usefull...

Comment: @privetDruzia: I don't want to be rude, but the problem I see is, that you simply copy'n'pasted your Makefile from various sources, without actually comprehending what's going on. The same goes for your linker problem. In fact your specific question has been asked countless times on StackOverflow, your particular flavour just adds Makefiles into the mix. For example your Makefile has the CFLAGS variable expansion in the wrong place (it belongs into the compilation phase, not the linking phase). The order of libraries as passed to the linker matters.

Comment: @It is a makefile (for a previous exercise in 2D) provided by our teacher. He teaches me so excuse me for not seeing the error my teacher makes...

Comment: @privetDruzia: See my answer update. I added a fixed Makefile that will get the job done (assuming that your source file is name `vlucht.c`) you may rename to your desire.

Comment: This solved the issue thank you! Here you go, just accepted and upvoted your answer

Comment: @privetDruzia: Still you should try to understand what's actually happening there. This is a starting point to understand implicit rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules